# Bash shell: command not found

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

I am using the shell module to execute the following command

```
 tasks:

  - name: Command
    shell: "sshpass -p 123 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@10.67.13.50 shell << EOF \n whoami\nEOF | cat"
```

I am getting the following error

```
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: line 2: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')",
        "Warning: Permanently added '10.67.13.50' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.",

        "bash: shell: command not found"
    ]
```

What is wrong with my command?

Comment: Remove the `| cat` - why it's there?

Comment: You don't have a program on the remote host named `shell`, apparently.

Comment: @chepner : This is the second error. The first error message relates to an unterminated HERE document. I don't know _ansible_, but it looks to me as if the `\n` sequence is not translated by ansible into a linefeed, but passed literally to `sh`.

Comment: @user1934428 That's just a warning. I agree that there's a semantic error, but `bash` will happily terminate a here document at the end of a file rather than rejecting it. (The *contents* of the here document won't be correct, though. YAML allows `\n` as a digraph; my guess is that the string is subject to shell intepretation first, though, and `\n` is being replaced with just `n`. `\\n` might be a fix.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr you can either a) replace `shell` with `sh` or `bash`, or b) replace `shell` with `whoami` and drop the heredoc.

Let's decompose the `shell` command:

> `sshpass -p 123 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@10.67.13.50 shell << EOF \n whoami\nEOF | cat`

There are several processes happening here.

- A `sh` pipeline with two subprocesses:

  - `sshpass` which then runs as a subprocess…

    - `ssh` which connects to `10.67.13.50` and runs…

      - `shell` with `\n whoami\n` as its standard input
  - … and `cat`, which takes the output from the `sshpass` process hierarchy

There are a couple potential bugs:

1. You can safely remove `cat` from the pipeline.

   As [@KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) mentioned, `cat` reads from its input and writes it out. It isn't doing anything here; it's neither useful nor harmless.
2. `shell` is not a command on the remote server (`10.67.13.50`). If you want to run a shell, typically `sh` or `bash` is used.
3. Moreover, you can replace the entire `shell … EOF` sequence with `whoami`.

   The `<< EOF \n whoami \nEOF` is a heredoc to tell the shell on the remote server what commands to execute. However, there is only one command executed.

In summary, the `shell:` line could be rewritten as:

> `sshpass -p 123 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@10.67.13.50 whoami`

… an odd command, since we know the remote user `root`.

Comment: you're right, removing the word "shell" and "| cat" solved the problem thanks. "sshpass -p 123 ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@10.67.13.50 << EOF \n whoami\nEOF"

Comment: Like the answer already says, the here document is useless, too.